# Is is possible to make tableview section headers scroll with the cells in a plain tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

In a grouped tableview, the section headers and footers scroll with the cells. However, in a plain tableview, they are fixed to the top and bottom of the screen until the next section is reached.

Is there a way to override this action and make the headers and footers scroll with the cells in a plain tableview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a plain tableview I am pretty sure that you cannot change the way sections headers scroll.

BUT, you might be able to get a similar effect. If you leave out the section headers and instead put the header into the first cell of the section, then it will definately scroll the way you want it to.

Then you have to do some work to make the first cell appear to be a header instead of just another cell. That would include delegate functions such as:

To prevent the "header" cell from getting selected:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

To change the appearance of the "header" cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: This is the only solution. Kinda sucks you can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I think the headers you are thinking of are section headers/index that stay over the cells until the next section replaces the current one.

The headers that I am thinking of will scroll off the screen immediately as you scroll down, and there is a similar footer that becomes visible at the very end.  HEre is the code I use to set up the header:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    highScoreData = [HighScoreData get];
    highScoresTable.tableHeaderView = highScoresTableHeaderView;
}
```

highScoresTableHeaderView is a simple view (IBOutlet) with some labels in my .xib.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView   *highScoresTableHeaderView;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need these to be section headers. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: You should then make a cell be your header.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath, check the indexpath. If you are at the end of a section or beginning of one, then use that cell as your header.  Don't forget to increment your cell count by the number of these header cells. And then add code to prevent the hilighting of these cells or selection of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your headers to stick to the top you should use "normal" `UITableViewCells` for your headers.

#### So instead of this:

> Number of sections: 2
>   Number of cells per section: 2
>
> - **Section 1**
>
>   - Cell 1a
> - Cell 1b
> - **Section 2**
>
>   - Cell 2a
>   - Cell 2b

You would have this:

> Number of sections: `default` (= 1)
>   Number of cells per section: 2 Header + 2*2 Cells = 6
>
> - **Cell 1** (cell that looks like a header previously `Section 1`)
> - Cell 2 ("normal cell" previously `Cell 1a`)
> - Cell 3 ("normal cell" previously `Cell 1b`)
> - **Cell 4** (cell that looks like a header previously `Section 2`)
> - Cell 5 ("normal cell" previously `Cell 2a`)
> - Cell 6 ("normal cell" previously `Cell 2b`)

Like this your header cells don't scroll and in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you need to decide which "cell template" to choose depending on the `indexPath`.

#### Update:

Another option is to change the tableview style to grouped. There the headers don't stick to the top as well.